# how to get updated value of a variable from another script to main.dart

Tags: flutter, dart

[home_screen.dart ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQfel.png)

how to get updated value of a variable from another script to main. dart? For example i've two dart script A and B and I defined Get Set method in B script and want to get the value using Get method from the B script to A script which is main. dart in my case.

Script main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertravelapp/screens/category_screen.dart';
import 'package:fluttertravelapp/screens/favorites_screen.dart';
import 'package:fluttertravelapp/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:fluttertravelapp/screens/search_screen.dart';
import 'package:fluttertravelapp/widgets/bottom_navigation_bar.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyHomePage());
}

final List<Widget> _children = [
  HomeScreen(),
  FavoritesScreen(),
  CategoryScreen(),
  SearchScreen()
];


class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  final BottomNavigationBarTravel barTravel = new BottomNavigationBarTravel();


  int _incrementCounter() {
    int index = 0;
    setState(() {
      index = barTravel.getIndex;
      print(index);
    });
    return index;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: _children[_incrementCounter()],
    );
  }
}
```

Script bottomnavigationbar.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class BottomNavigationBarTravel extends StatefulWidget {
  static int screenIndex = 0;

  // Creating the getter method
  // to get input from Field/Property
  int get getIndex {
    return screenIndex;
  }

  // Creating the setter method
  // to set the input in Field/Property
  set setIndex(int index) {
    screenIndex = index;
  }
  @override
  _BottomNavigationBarTravelState createState() =>
      _BottomNavigationBarTravelState();
}

class _BottomNavigationBarTravelState extends State<BottomNavigationBarTravel> {

  BottomNavigationBarTravel barTravel = new BottomNavigationBarTravel();

  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
      barTravel.setIndex = _selectedIndex;
      //print(barTravel.getIndex);
    });
    //print(barTravel.screenIndex);
  }

  var bottomNavStyle =
      GoogleFonts.lato(fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500);



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 86.4,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
            spreadRadius: 2,
            blurRadius: 15,
            offset: Offset(0, 5))
      ]),
      child: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: _selectedIndex == 0
                  ? new SvgPicture.asset('assets/svg/icon_home_colored.svg')
                  : new SvgPicture.asset('assets/svg/icon_home.svg'),
              title: Text('Home'),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: _selectedIndex == 1
                  ? new SvgPicture.asset('assets/svg/icon_heart_colored.svg')
                  : new SvgPicture.asset('assets/svg/icon_heart.svg'),
              title: Text('Heart'),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: _selectedIndex == 2
                  ? new SvgPicture.asset('assets/svg/icon_plus_colored.svg')
                  : new SvgPicture.asset('assets/svg/icon_plus.svg'),
              title: Text('Plus'),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: _selectedIndex == 3
                  ? new SvgPicture.asset(
                      'assets/svg/icon_search_colored.svg')
                  : new SvgPicture.asset('assets/svg/icon_search.svg'),
              title: Text('Search'),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: _selectedIndex == 4
                  ? new SvgPicture.asset('assets/svg/icon_user_colored.svg')
                  : new SvgPicture.asset('assets/svg/icon_user.svg'),
              title: Text('User'),
            )
          ],
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          onTap: _onItemTapped,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          selectedFontSize: 12,
          showSelectedLabels: false,
          showUnselectedLabels: false,
          elevation: 0,
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you can use State Management for this purpose such as Provider,Bloc,GetX etc.

Comment: can you elaborate, since i'm new to flutter and dart

Comment: can you elaborate, since I'm new to flutter and dart. But what i get from you, is I've already uses setState in incrementCounter method for getting the updated value.

Comment: setState updates the current screen if you want to pass data from one screen to another then you have to use StateManagement

Comment: thanks brother but can you provide guide or example code related to StateManagement.

Comment: yep, you can refer to this https://pub.dev/packages/provider/example I think this will solve your issue if still this doesn't please let me know, also if worked please mark as useful. Thanks

Comment: thanks brother you are very helpful, as I said I'm new to flutter, I don't understand the code link you provided. please help at last fourth line of main.dart "home: _children[_incrementCounter()]" I'm not able to get updated value from bottomnavigationbar script to main.dart.

Comment: you are having problem in bottom navigation? means can't navigate to other screen?

Comment: yes brother!!!!

Comment: where is your Scaffold?

Comment: I don't use Scaffold, instead design my custom UI. Also I learned flutter myself online.

Comment: can you show the page where you are calling your bottom nav?

Comment: Yes it's called in home_screen.dart . I've also attached the screenshot in the start of the question.

Comment: Thanks @Diwyansh. I just able to figure and solve the problem. Again thanks for your help and for pointing out where I'd called the Bottom navigation bar. Now I've called bottomnavigationbar in main.dart and fixes bottomanavigationbar script using scaffold and into it body property.

Comment: good to hear that :)